# Can someone help me to convert this floating-point number to a decimal number?

Tags: floating-point

I learned how to convert an IEEE-754 number, with 32 or 63 bits to decimal, but with less bits I have problems.

For example

```
11111111 (8 bits) = -31
```

My exponent is 3, and my fraction is 4.

the first bit from 11111111 is the sign bit.
then 3 bits are the exponent and the last 4 bits are the fraction or?

But how can I convert 1111111 with this information to -31?

Comment: Why should this correspond to -31?

Comment: we have a example in which 11111111 is -31, and i forgot to say that the excess constant is 3, but i dont now what this mean

Comment: @helpd Certainly a"IEEE-754 number, with 32 or 63 bits " should be "IEEE-754 number, with 32 or 64 bits ".  Perhaps edit your post if you agree.

Answer (score 2):

In an IEEE-754 encoding, an exponent of all 1's would correspond to either an infinity or a NaN. Apparently, your professor chose an encoding that does not conform to IEEE-754. So, your question is impossible to answer: You have to tell us exactly what the encoding is!

However, let's make the assumption that aside from ignoring infinity/NaN values, the encoding follows that of IEEE-754. (This is a big assumption, but seems to be the case here. Again, check with your professor.) Here's how you decode your value:

- 1 bit sign. Since it's set, this'll be a negative number,
- 3 bit exponent: 111. This is 7 in decimal; with a bias of 3 (what you call excess constant); so the unbiased exponent is 7-3=4. That is, we'll multiply the final result with `2^4`. (This is where we're diverging from regular IEEE754; if it was compliant, we'd have said this is a NaN since the significand isn't 0.)
- 4 bit significand, with an implicit one. So, we have "1.1111" as our significand value, in binary. This is similar to regular binary notation, just the exponents go decreasing after the dot. We get: `2^0 + 2^-1 + 2^-2 + 2^-3 + 2^-4`.

When you put it all together, the value is:

```
  -1 * 2^4 * (2^0 + 2^-1 + 2^-2 + 2^-3 + 2^-4)
= -1 * (2^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0)
= -1 * (16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1)
= -1 * 31
= -31
```

which is what you were predicting.

For details on how IEEE-754 is decoded, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format which is specific to the so called 32-bit single-precision format; which is what I used above adopted to your 8-bit format, with the infinity/NaN values ignored.